# How do you Defer Parsing of JavaScript for YouTube video on a WordPress site?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I just today realized that of my 1.2 MB site (per GTMetrix), 550k of it is a YouTube video.

My web site is a WordPress site, and the current video loads in an iframe.

I want my site to load faster... And not sure how to proceed. If I can make the YouTube video not load until clicked, and just have a thumbnail there instead, it seems like that would be the right play?

Comment: `What is the best route to take to fix this?` fix what? You haven't really stated what you want fixed, or what is broken - you've stated some facts that have no problem in them

Comment: Sorry.  Edited to reflect my desires.

Comment: look into how to have the youtube video not auto play - in that case it shouldn't start downloading data until the user presses play

Comment: if you have `&autoplay=1` in the url of the iframe, remove it, you'll be golden

Comment: No... it doesn't auto play.  It still loads about 550k of data even with Autoplay off.

Comment: That's odd - mine only loads 12K

Comment: What is the URL in the iframe src (excluding the 11 character youtube "code")

Comment: <iframe width="470" height="264" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/FtmR34ieWfk?rel=0&controls=0&showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Comment: strange that is should download that much

Comment: Take a look at: http://www.labnol.org/internet/light-youtube-embeds/27941/

Comment: @AhmedEssam - if you bothered to read the comments you'd see that he's using that method

Comment: @JaromandaX I am afraid you misunderstood, he is not using the method in the link. Please read the article in the link to the end. Thank you

Comment: sorry @AhmedEssam - I guess I should've bothered to read the whole article you posted :p

Comment: @JaromandaX no problem :) I fall in this all the time

Answer (score 17):

**1. Replace “scr” with “data-src”**

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/123456789" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

**2. Add Javascript**

```
function init() {
var vidDefer = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
for (var i=0; i<vidDefer.length; i++) {
if(vidDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src')) {
vidDefer[i].setAttribute('src',vidDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src'));
} } }
window.onload = init;
```

Now your site will load faster compared to past.

I have following this blog and it's working for me : http://www.codecanal.com/defer-parsing-javascript-youtube-videos/

Comment: My site homepage loaded 4 youtube videos. It's assign correct src value in first iframe. Other three iframe src assign as "unknown"

Comment: @VinothRaja can you provide me you site link ?
So that I can check it.

Comment: Well, I tried using your code but Pagespeed Insight returns the exact same result:
"Some third-party embeds can be lazy loaded. Consider replacing them with a facade until they are required". 
Transfer Size
Main-Thread Blocking Time - 1,310 ms 
YouTube Embedded Player (Video)

Comment: To get this to work with Pagespeed Insight, you now have to load 'after' all of the onload elements have completed. Changing window.onload = init to window.setTimeout(init, 3000) will execute after a 3 second delay - adjust this to a number 'after' your page fully loads, and the Pagespeed Insights will then exclude it from it's calculations. If this number is too low, it includes it! (These tools are getting too clever... They obviously want to include deferred processing within these calculations)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with two simple steps......

1. Update your embed  code like flowing....

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="" data-src="generic_youtube_url" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

2. Here is the java script part....

```
function init() { 
var vidDefer = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
for (var i=0; i<vidDefer.length; i++) {
 if(vidDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src')) {
 vidDefer[i].setAttribute('src',vidDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src'));
 } } } window.onload = init;
```

Reference For more details:

https://scottdeluzio.com/defer-parsing-javascript-youtube-videos/

https://varvy.com/pagespeed/defer-videos.html

P.S. I am personally using this and it works.

Thanks
Sabbir H

Answer (score -3):

The best and faster thing to do is to replace the video iframe by something like a link or an image, and load the iframe on click or another event.

Ahmed Essam linked you a solution, but if you don't want or don't know how to edit files on your wordpress installation, the Embed Video Thumbnail plugin does the job:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/embed-video-thumbnail/