# How to defer javascript of an embedded YouTube video on Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, youtube

I want to defer the loading of a particular Javascript file. On GTMetrix, I get a 14 score under the 'Defer Loading Of Javascript' category. I want to defer the loading of this file:

https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/player_ias-vflRCamp0/en_US/base.js

[image]

I've tried inserting scripts in my Theme's Footer, right before the  tag. Here's what I've tried:

```
`<script type="text/javascript">
function parseJSAtOnload() {
var element = document.createElement("script");
element.src = "https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/player_ias-vflRCamp0/en_US/base.js";
document.body.appendChild(element);
}
if (window.addEventListener)
window.addEventListener("load", parseJSAtOnload, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
window.attachEvent("onload", parseJSAtOnload);
else window.onload = parseJSAtOnload;
</script>
```

`

I've also tried:

```
`<script type="text/javascript">
function downloadJSAtOnload() {
var element = document.createElement("script");
element.src = "https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/player_ias-vflRCamp0/en_US/base.js";
document.body.appendChild(element);
}
if (window.addEventListener)
window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
</script>`
```

These scripts do nothing to the GTMetrix score.

I've tried this as well:

```
`<script type="text/javascript">
function parseJSAtOnload() {
var links = ["www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/player_ias-vflRCamp0/en_US/base.js", "www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/www-embed-player-vflO7uv3_/www-embed-player.js"],
headElement = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],
linkElement, i;
for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
linkElement = document.createElement("script");
linkElement.src = links[i];
headElement.appendChild(linkElement);
}
}
if (window.addEventListener)
window.addEventListener("load", parseJSAtOnload, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
window.attachEvent("onload", parseJSAtOnload);
else window.onload = parseJSAtOnload;
</script>`
```

This script will work temporarily. I'll test the page on GTMetrix and it shows that the Javascript is deferred. On the Waterfall chart, it shows that those scripts are canceled (insight here would be appreciated as well?)

When I Retest to make sure it's working, I'm back to the original score of 14. What else can I try, or what am I doing wrong?

Website Here: https://www.fralinpickups.com/product/vintage-hot/

Answer (score 0):

You should create a file with your code and queue it with `[wp_enqueue_script][1]` hook.

If your file is called my_script.js and it is in the folder /js/ of your theme, the function should look like this:

```
// You probably already have a function to enqueue scripts in your theme function.php file.
function my_script() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/my_script.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_script' );
```

The key to load it after other scripts is in the fifth parameter of the function, when set to true it loads the script in the footer, before the body tag. If your script requires jQuery and/or other dependencies you can add them in the array using the corresponding handle, as indicated in the documentation ([here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)).

If you want to asign defer to the script tag you could use the following:

```
function add_defer_attribute($tag, $handle) {
    if ( 'my_script' !== $handle )
        return $tag;
    return str_replace( ' src', 'defer="defer" src', $tag );
}
add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'add_defer_attribute', 10, 2);
```

More info on [script_loader_tag](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/script_loader_tag/).

**Update:**

Here is a valid answer that can help you with deferring youtube javascript: [How do you Defer Parsing of JavaScript for YouTube video on a WordPress site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38864444/how-do-you-defer-parsing-of-javascript-for-youtube-video-on-a-wordpress-site)

Comment: So, something like this? 

`/** enque youtube script */

function youtube_script() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'youtube_script.js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/youtube_script.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'youtube_script.js' );

function add_defer_attribute($tag, $handle) {
    if ( 'youtube_script.js' !== $handle )
        return $tag;
    return str_replace( ' src', 'defer="defer" src', $tag );
}
add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'add_defer_attribute', 10, 2);`

Comment: Yes, let me know the result.

Comment: It's still giving me the defer parsing of Javascript message on GTMetrix. Any other ideas? Thank you, Kevin.