# Files loading twice

Tags: javascript, wordpress, youtube, loading

I have been told that files will not be loaded twice as the browser will cache duplicate files but when i embed 2 videos

[image]

You can see all these files loading twice and they are all exactly the same the only difference is a cookie. Can someone explain why it requests the "base.js" file twice and how to prevent files loading more than once if they are the same?

Comment: How are you embedding them?

Comment: with the youtube embed button below the video

Comment: What is the value of `cache-control` response header?

Comment: public, max-age=31536000

Comment: Under the network tab in developer tools, is `Disable cache` selected?

Comment: It was when i checked but I disabled it and kept hitting refresh and still getting duplicates

Comment: The other possible reason can be, that the browser is fetching both files in parallel. So, the first one might not be cached yet. You can have a look at the `Waterfall` column in the network tab, to get an idea if that is the case.

Comment: You are correct they are both loading at the same time. What would be my best cause of action?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but may be something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/51588696/4350275